# Use sed to keep only parts of a file and reorder it (based on textWrangler grep syntax)

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

I want to edit a file called `trial.fastq` with the following format:

```
@NAME123.15.1 15 length=151
GTAGCNTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGGGGAATTTTCC
+NAME123.15.1 15 length=151
AAABB#>>AABDGCEGGGFGGGHHHGGGFHHGHH
@NAME123.14.1 14 length=150
TTCGCNTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCC
+NAME123.14.1 14 length=150
ABBBB#>>ABBBGGGGGEGGGGHDGFFFHHGHHH
```

I want to change the format to this:

```
@Inst:1:FID:LANE:TILE:15:Y 1:Y:0:NAME123
+GTAGCNTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGGGGAATTTTCC
@Inst:1:FID:LANE:TILE:14:Y 1:Y:0:NAME123
+TTCGCNTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCC
```

I've tried many formats of `sed` including:

```
sed -i -E 's/@(\w+).(\d+).(\d)\s\d+\slength=\d+\n.*/@Inst:1:FID:LANE:TILE:\2:Y \3:Y:0:\1\n/g' trial.fastq > trial_new.fastq
```

which I found from copying my TextWrangler find and replace grep search. As well as:

```
sed -e 's/\(@\w\).\(\d..+\).\(\d\)\s\d..*\slength\=\d..*\n.*$(\w..*)\(.*\)$\+.*$.*$/@Inst\:1\:FID\:LANE\:TILE\:\2\:Y \3\:Y\:0\:\1\n\4/g' trial.fastq
```

I am pretty sure I am going about this the wrong way. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Note that depending on your sed flavor `\d` is not a digit. That's a typical pitfall for people used to regexp in other tools

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you desired output correctly!

```
$ sed -nr '/#/d;s/@([^\.]+)[^ ]+ ([0-9]+) .*/@Inst:1:FID:LANE:TILE:\2:Y 1:Y:0:\1/p;s/^[A-Z]/\+&/p' file
@Inst:1:FID:LANE:TILE:15:Y 1:Y:0:NAME123
+GTAGCNTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTGGGGAATTTTCC
@Inst:1:FID:LANE:TILE:14:Y 1:Y:0:NAME123
+TTCGCNTACGGGAGGCAGCAGTAGGGAATCTTCC
```

#### Explanation

- `-n` don't print until we ask for it
- `-r` use ERE
- `/#/d` delete lines with `#`
- `([^\.]+) save some characters that are not`.` for later
- `[^ ]+ ([0-9]+) .*` save some numbers between spaces
- `\1` backreference to saved pattern in replacement
- `;` separates commands, like in the shell
- `s/^[A-Z]/\+&/` replace lines that start with a capital letter with themselves prefixed with `+`
- `p` print the lines we worked on

Use the `-i` flag if you want to edit the file in place, after testing the output is what you want (repeat the command with `sed -nri ....`)